# Chrome extension: chrome.scripting.executeScript not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, execute-script

for some reason my `executeScript` function is not working.
This is my code:

```
async function scrape_get_url(){
    console.log("Getting url: " + from_url);
    var tab_id;
    chrome.tabs.create({ "url": from_url}, function(newTab){
        tab_id = newTab.id;
        console.log("Checking for tab url update");
    });
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function(tabId, info) {
        if(tabId == tab_id && info.url){
            console.log("Executing scrape script");
            console.log("tab id:" + tab_id);
            console.log("updated tab url:" + info.url);
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: {tabId: tab_id},
                function: scrape
            });
        }
    });
}
function scrape(){
    console.log("Getting Element...");
}
```

This is my output:

```
Getting url: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted
Checking for tab url update
Executing scrape script
tab id:293
updated tab url:https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/
```

I have an `onUpdated` listener due to a chrome bug, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68611210/navigate-tab-to-a-url-and-execute-script-inside). Also, the reason I put the `onUpdated` function outside of the `create` function's callback, is because according to another question on StackOverflow(that I can't find anymore :/ ), putting the `executeScript` within the `create`'s callback will not run the script.

My permissions are set correctly in the manifest file.

Comment: The code is fine. Your mistake is probably that you look in the wrong console. The executed script runs in the web page so you need to look in its devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hey, you were right! My bad... Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0):

I saw the chromium bug report, and I dug deep into this.

I don't have a solution, I have a hack that works.

```
function _func(res){
    setTimeout( () => {
    // Do things with the page.
    }, 3000);
}
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.example.com'}).then((tab) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: {tabId: tab.id},
                func: _func //,
                // I used args in my case, you dont have to. args: [msg.content]
            })
        }, 3000)
    });
```

Comment: My problem was that I was looking into the wrong console. The executed script runs in its own window and you have to look into that window's console.